# Finding out name decoration

Tags: c++, dll, vb6, activex, name-decoration

I have an ActiveX DLL that I am integrating with a standard third party client. To achieve this, I had to include a custom DEF file, a proxy linker, and self-initialize the COM libraries.

When I test my ActiveX DLL with a client I created, it does run fine. However, when I include the ActiveX DLL with the third party client, it crashes in certain function calls. I believe the crashing is a result of a mismatch in the naming decoration.

Is there a way I can verify the name decoration that the third party client program requires?

Thanks,

Comment: If I understand what you mean there is no "name decoration" in C. Tag removed.

Comment: As given the question appears to be too vague to give any meaningful answer or advice.

Comment: Did you try `dumpbin.exe /imports client.exe`?

Comment: This is nothing to do with the naming of the exports. In fact, if this is an ActiveX component, only the standard COM exports matter at all (DllGetClassObject et al).

What is the full call stack of the crash you see?

Answer (score 1):

Dependency walker can show you what is exported from DLLs:

http://dependencywalker.com/

However, if there is a name mismatch you will get an error or exception.  It is more likely you are passing a bad parameter.

[Edit]
Dependency Walker shows you the external functions that are being called and tries to match them to the dll:

[image]

Comment: I used Dependency Walker but I could only find the signatures of the dll. The signatures that the client program requires do not appear. Can this be displayed?

Comment: Thanks for the image. For some reason, the function matching is shown in all the DLLs that are under the respective exe. However, there are some DLLs that appear at the same level than the other main exe, and the top window appears empty. The DLL is also called by the exe, by chance, do you know why it does not appear under?